# drag constraints in raphael.js and zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I've had no problem getting a basic zoom/pan effect with Raphael.js 2.0 using PAN :

```
set = ( // set of elements, contained in a rectangle)
var start = function () {
        set.oBB = set.getBBox();
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
        var bb = set.getBBox();
                set.translate(set.oBB.x - bb.x + dx, set.oBB.y - bb.y + dy);
},
up = function() { // do stuff };
set.drag(move, start, up);
```

and ZOOM :

```
//before 
paper.setViewBox(0,0, 500,500, false);
//after
paper.setViewBox(0,0, 200, 200, false);
```

BUT I'm having two big problems with this. This is for a raphael-created svg object and not for an image...

- First, panning AFTER the zoom is not 'smooth' : I drag a little and the rectangle moves a lot. The movement gets worse the farther I go along. Can I scale the drag somehow when I have zoomed?
- Second, how do I arrange so that the panning the zoomed rectangle doesn't let me move it out of the viewport? In jquery I could do this with a constraint, and I've tried playing with the set.translate function above to include constraints but I'm getting nowhere...

Any advice would be appreciated, or else a library which already exists for doing this in Raphael.js? I looked at raphael-spz which doesn't seem to address either of my problems above.

What I'd like is basically this http://dannyvankooten.com/demo/draggable-image-map-with-zoom/ but for Raphael. He's using jquery ui draggable... which I can't seem to get to work in Raphael.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have scaled the viewbox you might need to scale the drag values as well, fro calculating bounds you can just compare against the viewport, something like,

```
move = function (dx, dy) {
        var bb = set.getBBox(),
            //Move relative to viewport scale
            x = dx/scale,
            y = dy/scale,
            //Lower bounds
            xf = Math.max(0, set.oBB.x - bb.x + x),
            yf = Math.max(0, set.oBB.y - bb.y + y);
         //upper bounds
         xf = Math.min(viewBoxWidth, xf + bb.width) - bb.width;
         yf = Math.min(viewBoxHeight, yf + bb.height) - bb.height;

         set.translate(xf, yf);
}
```

`scale` being the factor that your viewbox is different relative to your paper. ie(`200/500)`

Comment: thanks @Andrew - that worked nicely, but with 500/200 rather than 200/500 ;) Any ideas for the second part of my question?

Comment: @Petrov There is probably an easier way, but I updated with the most straight forward.

Comment: thanks @Andrew for the update, but this is having the same problem I was having before - panning positive (x or y) then panning negative (x or y) is not possible, and also leads to a big jump on the next click  - here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/TZusb/

Comment: @Petrov I probably should have asked for that in the beginning, that is easy to do. http://jsfiddle.net/TZusb/1/